# JavaScript, creation of large files (more than 2 gb) to download from the client

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am implementing a websocket server to transfer files to clients, that is, I send the bytes of the file in parts from the server to the client, and from the client I join the byte fragments and create the file with its extension.

My problem is that the string apparently can only store and concatenate only up to 500mb approx, which would limit the generation of larger files such as 1gb or greater since it freezes.

Is there any way to buffer that large amount of data and be able to download it as files?

I have searched and found about StreamSaver.js but I have not been able to implement it with the internet examples to create that giant data buffer. Thanks!

I leave a sample of my code to pass from a hex string to files.

```
function CreateFile(DataHex, FileName) {
var binary = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<DataHex.length/2; i++) {
var h = DataHex.substr(i*2, 2);
binary[i] = parseInt(h,16);
}
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(binary);
var filecomp = window.document.createElement('a');
filecomp.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }));
filecomp.download = FileName;
filecomp.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(filecomp.href);
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending the file as a giant string instead of sending it as binary data?

Comment: My websocket server is written in vb. I experience more encoding issues that way when it's already coming to the client as utf8 for ANSI encoded files.

Comment: well, another encoding issue will arise as every character in a string in js is 2 bytes. 0xFD is 1 byte as binary data. "FD" is 4 bytes as a utf8 encoded string. And then you'll have to do another conversion hoping you don't lose data trying to convert it back and save it on the client.

Comment: My method is certainly inefficient when it comes to saving resources, but it works very well for me when it comes to keeping all the data. (I can send files between 200-250mb without any problem, not losing anything). My big problem is how to create a buffer in js that stores large amounts of bytes.